# using a regex to split the parenthesis in a a string

Tags: python, regex

i need to split the parenthesis of a polynomial, something like this.
`'ac*(ab+(2ab+4ac))'` --> `['ac*',['ab+',['2ab+4ac']]]`.
i tried using this regex but there is something wrong. `\[[^\]]*\]|\([^\)]*\)|\"[^\"]*\"|\S+`

Comment: Are you trying to make the regex match every component of the split-up string? Did you notice there is a `re.split`?

Comment: Can the string have an arbitrary number of levels of nested parentheses? A question stated in terms of a single example is rarely unambiguous. In any event, I don't think a regular expression is the right tool here. Instead I think you need a recursive method that looks at the string character-by-character, using a stack to identify matching pairs of parentheses. I would offer an answer that does that if I knew Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 2,

Translation of @Cary Swoveland's Ruby code to Python to demo the recursive way to do this as well!

```
def polyparse(string):
  start_idx = 0
  curr_idx = 0
  arr = []
  while curr_idx != len(string):
    try:
      lft_idx = string.index('(', curr_idx)  
    except ValueError:
      arr.append(string[curr_idx:len(string)+1])
      break
    if lft_idx > curr_idx:
      arr.append(string[curr_idx:lft_idx])
    rt_idx = find_matching(string, lft_idx+1)
    # code here to raise exception if rt_idx.nil?
    if rt_idx > lft_idx + 2:
      arr.append(polyparse(string[lft_idx+1:rt_idx]))
    curr_idx = rt_idx + 1
  return arr

def find_matching(string, start_idx):
  nbr_unmatched = 0
  for i in range(start_idx, len(string)):
    c = string[i]
    if c == ')':
      if nbr_unmatched == 0:
        return i
      nbr_unmatched = nbr_unmatched - 1
    if c == '(':
      nbr_unmatched = nbr_unmatched + 1
  return None

print(polyparse("ac*(ab+(2ab+4ac))"))

print(polyparse("ac*(ab+(2ab+4*(ac+bd)))+((x+2)*3)"))
```

Returns:

```
['ac*', ['ab+', ['2ab+4ac']]]
['ac*', ['ab+', ['2ab+4*', ['ac+bd']]], '+', [['x+2'], '*3']]
```

Edit 1, original method wouldn't work on more complex polynomials, thank you @Cary Swoveland for pointing that out! Similar idea though as before, convert it to a string rep and then use json to safely parse to list:

```
import json
import re

def to_list(polynomial_exp):
  v = '[' + ''.join([x.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']' ) for x in [x if re.search(r'(\(|\))', x) else ',"' + x + '",' for x in [x for x in re.split(r'(\(|\))', polynomial_exp) if x != '']]]) + ']'
  return json.loads(v.replace('[,', '[').replace(',]', ']'))

# original example: 
to_list('ac*(ab+(2ab+4ac))')

# more complex example:
to_list("ac*(ab+(2ab+4*(ac+bd)))+((x+2)*3)")
```

Output:

```
>>> to_list('ac*(ab+(2ab+4ac))')
['ac*', ['ab+', ['2ab+4ac']]]
>>> to_list("ac*(ab+(2ab+4*(ac+bd)))+((x+2)*3)")
['ac*', ['ab+', ['2ab+4*', ['ac+bd']]], '+', [['x+2'], '*3']]
```

Comment: Clever! Try testing also with a more complex string, such as the second one in my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ahh you're totally right that was not going to work on more complex examples. updated the idea for the string rep- thank you!

Comment: I wasn't right. I didn't know. :-) Perhaps you could do more modification before `json.loads`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland well, your suggestion caught the bug so that merits a thank you! :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Oh oops didn't see that- I just read the code part, but I translated yours to Python! Instead of deleting your answer, you can copy my translated version and add it to yours and I'll remove it from mine- since I didn't actually come up with it

Comment: Looks good, Anna. I will delete my answer because only Python solutions should survive. It would be cleaner to make the code you added a separate answer. (It’s not unusual to see two answers given by the same person.) If you wish to mention my contribution (though I don’t care about that) I suggest you do that in a comment on the answer, to keep the answer clean and focussed. You may want add to add some comments explaining your code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it looks like he selected this one as the answer already so I will just leave this one up with your mention in it! I also hope you leave the Ruby answer up because I think it might be useful for others to see how to translate back and forth between these two languages and, IMO, the teamwork between our two answers is the best thing about stack overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the strings can have arbitrary levels of nested parentheses, I don't believe that a regular expression is the right tool to produce the desired array. Not knowing Python, I am offering a (recursive) solution in Ruby. As the two languages are similar in many ways I am hopeful that a reader will offer a Python solution using an algorithm similar to the one I've employed. (Even readers who don't know Ruby can probably figure out my algorithm.) I will delete my answer if and when a Python solution along these lines is posted.

```
def polyparse(str)
  start_idx = 0
  curr_idx = 0
  arr = []
  loop do
    return arr if curr_idx == str.size 
    lft_idx = str.index('(', curr_idx)        
    return arr << str[curr_idx..-1] if lft_idx.nil?
    arr << str[curr_idx..lft_idx-1] if lft_idx > curr_idx
    rt_idx = find_matching(str, lft_idx+1)
    # code here to raise exception if rt_idx.nil?
    arr << polyparse(str[lft_idx+1..rt_idx-1]) if rt_idx > lft_idx + 2
    curr_idx = rt_idx + 1
  end 
end
```

```
def find_matching(str, start_idx)
  nbr_unmatched = 0
  (start_idx..str.size-1).each do |i|
    c = str[i]
    case c
    when ')'
      return i if nbr_unmatched.zero?
      nbr_unmatched -= 1
    when '('
      nbr_unmatched += 1
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

```
polyparse("ac*(ab+(2ab+4ac))")
  #=> ["ac*", ["ab+", ["2ab+4ac"]]]
polyparse("ac*(ab+(2ab+4*(ac+bd)))+((x+2)*3)")
  #=> ["ac*", ["ab+", ["2ab+4*", ["ac+bd"]]], "+", [["x+2"], "*3"]]
```

See [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-index) with particular reference to the second (optional) argument.

Note:

```
str = "ac*(ab+(2ab+4ac))"
       01234567890123456
           ^           ^
               ^      ^ 

find_matching(str, 3+1) #=> 16 
find_matching(str, 7+1) #=> 15
```

Comment: i don't know ruby but this seems working. good job and thanks for the help!